# What is the best book to prepare for Data structures and algorithms from scratch to advance level?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am a beginner in programming world and i have basic knowledge in Python Java and good knowledge in C++. I have started learning web development in my summer break and i would like to start Data structures and Algorithms .
Please suggest some good reference/book/content for my Data structures and Algorithms learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome :)

Unfortunately, since this question does not have a fully objective answer (i.e. answers vary on opinions), it is not a very good idea to ask it on Stackoverflow.

There are really nice books which we all still get help from. You can find them on web with a basic search, read comments, and so on.

I don't believe that you can choose a disaster-like book for beginning your adventure, I mean, you will learn a lot somehow.

While you are learning, do not hesitate to ask if you face with something which you would need help, just be careful about its answer being objective :)